# Show the close reason in the top bar when reviewing Reopen votes

Tags: feature-request, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

> ### tl;dr: Imbed the close reason in the top bar when reviewing Reopen votes.

Currently, the top bar when reviewing reopen votes (the one with the buttons on it) says this:

> This question was *edited* after it was closed. Should it be reopened?

One of the most important pieces of information when reviewing reopen votes is *what the post was closed as*.

I know that you *should* be able to just see if the post should be closed. If it shouldn't, reopen it. However, we live in real life.

In real life, it is often helpful to have the research of 5 other people to tell you why the post was closed in the first place. For example, one would take a much different approach to reviewing a reopen vote for a question that was closed as OT than one closed as NARQ.

I know that this information is already present, in the form of the close box underneath the question. But that's *so far down!* That requires *scrolling*, which translates to actual work!

When reviewing close votes, the top box thing says this:

> Should this be closed as **not a real question?**

So, why not make the reopen vote review queue symmetrical?

> This question was *edited* after it was closed as **not a real question**. Should it be reopened?

This one change would make reopen vote reviewers even lazier, and would reduce cases of repetitive motion injury caused by scrolling down to see close reasons.

Please don't give us repetitive motion injuries.