# Where's the close reason in an item in the re-open queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

Often I see something in the reopen queue, and I'm scratching my head trying to understand why it was closed in the first place.

I then scroll up and down the page looking for the close reason, and usually can't find it, just a message saying "This question was editted...".

This question [Show the close reason in the top bar when reviewing Reopen votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185579/show-the-close-reason-in-the-top-bar-when-reviewing-reopen-votes) seems to imply that the close reason is on the page but requires scrolling down. However, after opening the question, copying the close reason (in this case, "primarily opinion-based") and `ctrl-F`ing it, it's not on the page.

Am I missing something obvious? Does this vary from site to site and only SO shows the close reason (the site I was using was travel.SE)? Is there something obvious and intuitive I need to do to show the close reasons, like press `ctrl-alt-enter-7` three times then click on an empty space? Or is it by design that I have to open the question to see why it was closed?

Comment: Does it *really* matter *why* it was closed - the idea is that if you can't see a reason it should be - it should be open.

Comment: @JonClements in an ideal world it'd always be clear, but real life isn't ideal, and I'm not arrogant enough to simply assume "I don't see why this decision was made, therefore, those people were wrong". That'd be a terrible attitude. I always try to understand *why* people are wrong before concluding that they are `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

This is already part of the question that is showing in the review, you just have to scroll down in case of a long question.

In the common case of editing (which send the question to Reopen queue), you're right and the Revision tab doesn't show the close banner, so you'll have to click the left-most tab (Question (revised)) and you will see there the ordinary close message.